# Iterator does not including values added to it inside a loop

Tags: ruby, iterator

I have:

```
ids = [1]
```

I am doing `ids.each do |id|` to loop through `ids` and look for child ids to add to `ids`. Here's my code:

```
ids.each do |id|
  # Do some things
  ids |= search_for_more_ids(id)
end
```

During the first iteration, `ids` gets a second value and become `[1, 2]`. But the loop still exists on the first iteration. The iterator only runs once; the second value is never accessed. It's weird because this used to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Used to work when?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev when it was written in [tag:perl] (or [tag:c],) for instance.

Comment: It used to work up until recently, in ruby I think

Comment: @DavidSigley: proof (version number) is needed.

Comment: Ok, what would be the best solution for something like this then?

Comment: “what would be the best solution for something like this”—obviously, the recursion.

Comment: You should explain _why_ you are using `|=` and what you are trying to achieve. Maybe give some example input.

Answer (score 2):

> ids is now [1,2]

yes, name `ids` now points to an array which holds content `1, 2`, but that is a completely different array. Not the one you have created an iterator for, when you entered `.each`.

I would think hard (twice) before mutating a collection I'm iterating<strike>, but if you insist, then at least mutate the very same collection and don't create a new one. (this means, use `push`, not `|=`)</strike>.

---

> Ok, what would be the best solution for something like this then?

This looks like a job queue. This is traditionally implemented with a stack or a queue. We'll use an array here, for simplicity.

```
ids = [1]

loop do
  id = ids.shift
  puts id # your processing
  ids.concat(search_for_more_ids(id))
  break if ids.empty?
end
```

Comment: Please don’t advise mutating a collection while iterating it even with a preamble like this.

Comment: @mudasobwa: better now?

Comment: `ary.push(*other_ary)` -> `ary.concat(other_ary)`

Comment: And you could use `until ids.empty? do` instead of `loop do` and `break`, but that's a matter of taste.

Comment: @Stefan: IIRC, Matz recommends using loop/break combo

Comment: @SergioTulentsev wasn't that the modifier one? `begin .. end until condition`?

Comment: @Stefan: ah yes, I thought that is what you were proposing. My bad.

Comment: This solution misses the benefit of |= where I will not search through duplicated values, but thanks for this.

Comment: @DavidSigley this solution works, while `|=` does not. What benefits are you talking about? Use `uniq!` on the result.

Comment: @mudasobwa `uniq!` doesn't account for values that have already been processed (i.e. were `shift`-ed out of the array earlier)

Comment: @Stefan: yeah, that's another pattern. I usually create a hash/set `seen_this` (or something like that)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev indeed, you could push each `id` to a `processed_ids` array after processing and call `ids.concat(search_for_more_ids(id) - processed_ids)` to avoid duplicates.

Comment: @Stefan: i have a feeling that maintaining and consulting a "seen" set (not an array) would be significantly faster. But this needs to be measured.

Answer (score 2):

> However, the iterator only runs once. the second value is never accessed

Because **it's not there**. And it's clearly visible if you save the array you're iterating on to a place you can look at later (`memo` in my example):

```
ids = [1]
memo = ids
ids.each do |id|
  # Do some things
  ids |= search_for_more_ids(id)
  # ids is now [1,2] but the loop still exists on the first iteration
end
p memo # [1]
p ids  # [1, 2]
```

---

In general though, changing a collection you're walking through at the same time is very error-prone and for some collections isn't even possible. Delving deep into hacks like this may be worth performance-wise, but you probably need a working solution first. Start with that.

To do this **properly** I would probably use proper data structures for the job: a set for keeping track of searches already done and a queue for tracking the remaining searches (initialized with a single value of `1`). And the resulting algorithm pretty much explains itself:

```
require "set"
require "queue"

processed  = Set.new
to_process = Queue.new

to_process.push(1) # Enqueue the initial id to search

loop do
  break if to_process.empty?
  id = to_process.pop
  next unless processed.add?(id) # returns `nil` if it's already there
  search_for_more_ids(id).each do |new_id|
    to_process.push(new_id)
  end
end
```

You would get your result in a `Set` called `processed`.

It's also probably faster than your approach since it eliminates duplicates without intermediate container allocations; via set lookups. But that depends on sizes of the data you're dealing with (total amount of ids, lengths of individual search results). Some corners can be cut depending on specifics. For instance, you could modify the algorithm so that duplicates don't go through the queue at all — something I avoided intentionally to keep the code clear.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `puts memo.__id__ == ids.__id__` would probably illustrate it better.

Comment: So it's due to the assignment. What if we used `ids.concat(search_for_more_ids(id))` – would that be okay?

Comment: @Stefan unfortunately `concat` would work as expected for most rubies :(

Comment: @Stefan I don't think it would; `|` is not just "concat", it's "dedupe" as well. Well, paired with `uniq!` is probably as close as we could get to OP's intention and attempted approach. There are lots of other (most of them better) ways to do the same thing however.

Comment: _"There are lot of [...] better ways to do the same thing"_ – it doesn't seem that trivial, but maybe you could post one of them as an answer? ;-)

Comment: @Stefan sure thing.